# Graphics card issues?

Tags: gpu

I have an Intel GPU and I think that the catalyst GPU is AMD. However, I would like to install the latest drivers for this, but am having trouble as I cannot find out which driver I have to install. I wanted to play Halo CE but there were screen issues. My frind said it had something to do with the catalyst GPU drivers not being up to date. So any ideas on how to find out my catalyst GPU type? (HP Pavilion g6).

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: The proprietary graphics drivers in Ubuntu 14.04 are very good, good enough for gaming, so in additional to whatever else you do take a look at [How do I install additional drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers) and then select the most up-to-date **tested** graphics driver.

Comment: follow **karel's** link, or if you're interested in Catalyst you can take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)

Comment: It says that no catalyst drivers are in use, I just need to know my catalyst GPU type so I can get the driver.

Comment: what does `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` say?

Comment: billy@billy-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -nnk | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
billy@billy-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: did you check your bios settings? it can be disabled in bios. If you type `lspci | grep -i ati` or `amd` etc and nothing is found it can be disabled by default in bios, you need to look for it and enable it in bios.

Comment: the tutorial I sent you in my previous comment and a link from **karel** these are complete guides for installing video drivers.

Answer (score 1):

*I think that the catalyst GPU is AMD*. According to the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` you have no AMD GPU, and so your computer is already using the right graphics driver, the graphics driver that is built-in in Ubuntu.

Some models of the HP Pavilion g6 laptop have an additional discrete graphics processor and other models of the HP Pavilion g6 don't have one. For example, according to HP Pavilion g6-1304tx Notebook PC Product Specifications, that model of HP Pavilion g6 laptop, which has a 2nd Generation Intel Core i5 processor, does indeed also have an AMD Radeon HD 7450M graphics processor. If so, the correct graphics driver for that graphics processor would surely show up in the Additional Drivers utility. Search the Dash for *Additional Drivers* and click the Additional Drivers icon to open Additional Drivers to check if there is a proprietary graphics driver available for your laptop.